# What will be the cohesive energy of an alloy in LAMMPS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, metals, metal-complexes

The cohesive energy of a pure material is generally termed as the energy of a unit cell divided by the number of atoms. what will be cohesive energy of an alloy in LAMMPS? I am running LAMMPS for $\ce{UO2}$ with different potentials and found that the total energy of the system is different for different potentials, but the lattice parameter matches well.

Comment: +1 but please take a careful look at my edit to see some of the things you'd hopefully do next time so that others don't have to do it!

Comment: It is normal that you get different energy (even different results) with different potentials. This is one of the weakness of Molecular Mechanics: each forcefield is different and tailored to work well with a reduce set of atoms.

Comment: @Camps what about cohesive energy of alloy? Any idea

Comment: Maybe the definition here can help you: [What are the differences among the concepts: binding energy, cohesive energy and formation energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43935/264819)

Comment: @pranavkumar did the suggestion by Camps help you?

Comment: @NikeDattani we can close this question. Camps link doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Sure, we can close it. Unrelated to that: the link in Camps' last comment does work for me.

Comment: @NikeDattani I came through and fixed the link around the time of that comment, but I probably should have notified Pranav.

Comment: @NikeDattani  we can close this question.

Comment: @Tyberius or maybe notified us all, but changing a comment that says "March 27 '21" on it seems like it could cause confusion down the road. Maybe a better way would be to write a separate comment. In any case, OP said we can close the question now.